# The properties of convex function on the closed unit interval $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, absolute-continuity

Consider a continuous and convex function $F(x):[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$. I am wondering if

> 1. $F(x)$ is continuously differentiable in $[0,1]$
> 2. $F(x)$ is of bounded variation in $[0,1]$
> 3. $F(x)$ is absolute continuous in $[0,1]$.

The second one is correct, due to this post [Proving a convex function is of bounded variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656953/proving-a-convex-function-is-of-bounded-variation).

However, the remaining two became mysterious to me. Royden's chapter 6 answers them if we have an open interval.

> Corollary 17: Let $\varphi$ be a convex function on $(a,b)$. Then $\varphi$ is Lipschitz, and therefore absolutely continuous on each closed, bounded subinterval $[c,d]$ and $(a,b)$
>
> Theorem 18: Let $\varphi$ be a convex function on $(a,b)$. Then $\varphi$ is differentiable except at a countable number of points.

By the Theorem 18, it is hard to believe that $F(x)$ will become differentiable in $[0,1]$. But I cannot find a counterexample. That is, a convex function that is continuous on $[0,1]$ but is not differentiable.

The Corollary 17 gives us pretty nice result, but seems like it does not apply to the closed interval. Is it possible to say that if we have $F(x)$ on $[0,1]$ is convex, then it will be convex on $(-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$? and then we can use Corollary 17 to conclude that it is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]\subset (-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$.

Thank you!

Comment: As a counterexample for 1, you can use $F(x)=|x - \frac{1}{2}|$. It is not differentiable at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @JPMarciano oh right. I thought $|x|$, but only god knows why i did not think about $|x-a|$ thank you!!

Comment: 3) is true. $F$ is the indefinite integral of its right-hand derivative.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy would you mind elaborating it?

Comment: Surely if a function is absolutely continuous on $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0, 1]$, it is automatically a.c. on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @JackM but I don't have tools to prove $F(x)$ is absolutely continuous on $(0,1)$. Royden's theorem only tells us if it is convex on $(a,b)$ then it will be absolutely continuous on every compact subintervals $[c,d]$ of it. Not from $[a,b]$ to $(c,d)$

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Should "and $(a,b)$" read "of $(a,b)$" in your statement of Corollary 17?

Comment: It seems to me that the key question here is about extensions of convex functions. Can a continuous convex function on a closed interval be extended to a neighborhood of that interval? Can a continuous convex function on an open interval be extended to its closure?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1590150.

Comment: @JackM yes. If we can fix this, we can use the theorem and corollary from Royden. But perhaps there is another way around.

Comment: @JackM oh sorry, yes. Royden's corollary, not theorem.

Comment: @MartinR In fact I did not find a convincing proof from this post and the post it linked to.

Comment: @JackM I guess we can construct a continuous convex function $f$ on a closed interval $[0,1]$ which cannot be extended to a continuous convex function on a neighborhood of that interval as follows. Let $a_0=0$ and $(a_n)$ be an increasing sequence of elements of $(0,1)$ tending to $1$. Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $f$ is linear on each segment $[a_n,a_{n+1}]$, but tangents of slopes of the graph of $f$ on these segments increase and tend to infinity.

Comment: @JackM Any unbounded (continuous convex) function on an open interval (for instance, $1/x$ on $(0,1)$)  cannot be extended to a continuous function on its closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given real numbers $a<b$, let us show that a continuous and convex function $F(x):[a,b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous. Since $F$ is a continuous function on a compact set $[a,b]$ it attains its minimum at some point $c\in [a,b]$. Convexity of $F$ implies that $F$ is non-increasing on $[a,c]$ and non-decreasing on $[c,b]$. So it suffices to
consider a case when $F$ is monotonic on $[a,b]$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be any number. Since the function $F$ is continuous at $a$ and $b$, there exist $0<\delta'<|b-a|$ such that if $x,y\in [a,b]$ and $|x-a|\le\delta’$, $|y-b|\le\delta’$ then $|F(a)-F(x)|\le\varepsilon/3$ and $|F(b)-F(y)|\le\varepsilon/3$. The monotonicity of $F$ implies that for any family $(x_n,y_n)$ of disjoint open intervals contained in $[a,a+\delta’]\cup [b-\delta’,b]$ we have $\sum |F(y_n)-F(x_n)|\le 2\varepsilon/3$.

By Corollary 17, $F$ is absolutely continuous on $(a+\delta’, b-\delta’)$, so there exists a real number $\delta\le \delta’$ such that for any finite family $(x_n,y_n)$ of disjoint open intervals contained in $(a+\delta’, b-\delta’)$ of the total length at most $\delta$ we have $\sum |F(y_n)-F(x_n)|\le \varepsilon/3$.

The above easily implies that any finite family $(x_n,y_n)$ of disjoint open intervals contained in $[a, b]$ of the total length at most $\delta$ we have $\sum |F(y_n)-F(x_n)|\le \varepsilon$.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late reply. Why does Corollary 17 imply the absolute continuity in that open interval? The corollary gives us the absolute continuity in the compact sub intervals, right?

Comment: I think perhaps you mean it is absolutly continuous on $[a+\delta', b-\delta']$?

Comment: and why you can choose $\delta$ to be such that $\delta\leq \delta'$?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical 1. $F$ is absolutely continuous on $[a+\delta’, b-\delta’]$ and so on its subset $(a+\delta’, b-\delta’)$. 2. The number $\delta$ can be diminished to be not biger than $\delta’$, keeping the required condition.

Comment: Okay. All set. Brilliant treatment around the boundary points!

Comment: oh by the way, the choice of $\delta'$. In fact since it is continuous around the boundary points, for $\epsilon>0$, we should have $\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ from the definition of continuity, and you take $\delta':=\min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$. Right? just double check

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Yes. In fact, the function $F$ is a continuous function on a compact set, so it is uniformly continuous, so given $\varepsilon$ we can pick $\delta’>0$ such that if $x,y\in [a,b]$ and $|x-y|\le\delta’$ then $|F(x)-F(y)|\le\varepsilon/3$.

Comment: Thank you so much!